# Maintain bootstrap 5 Tab State on Refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-5

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="my_tabs">
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> 
     <a class="nav-link active" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a> 
   </li>
   <li class="nav-item" role="presentation"> 
     <a class="nav-link" data-bs-toggle="pill" href="#tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a> 
   </li>
</ul>
      
<section class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
     Tab 1
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
     Tab 2
   </div>
</section>
```

How can I maintain the active tab after refreshing the page? Ive had a search and have not found the solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whenever the tab state changes, store the state somewhere. Recover the state on page load. BS5 tabs emit [events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/#events) when their state changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use JavaScript, not data- attributes.

So, [initiate tab with JavaScript](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#via-javascript), and then on each click, store the active tab id in localStorage.

On first load get the active tab id from localStorage, and activate it, or set default active tab id.

Example

(note: localStorage won't work here on SO, but it should work locally, i.e. where it's allowed to save to localStorage):

```js
const triggerTabList = document.querySelectorAll('#my_tabs a');

triggerTabList.forEach(triggerEl => {

  const tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl);

  triggerEl.addEventListener('click', event => {

    event.preventDefault();
    tabTrigger.show();

    // save tab target
    localStorage.setItem('active-tab', event.target.getAttribute('href'));

  });
});

// get the active tab id, set default
const activeTabId = localStorage.getItem('active-tab') || '#tab1';

// find the element that triggers the tab
const activeTab = [...triggerTabList].find(el => el.getAttribute('href') === activeTabId);

// click the element to trigger the tab
// in case it's not found, click the first tab
if (activeTab) {
  activeTab.click();
} else {
  triggerTabList[0].click();
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills" id="my_tabs">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab1" aria-selected="true">Tab 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#tab2" aria-selected="false">Tab 2</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<section class="tab-content" id="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1" role="tabpanel">
    Tab 1
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2" role="tabpanel">
    Tab 2
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks so much. Works perfectly.